# Visual artifacts showing up on decimated model set to "shade smooth"

Tags: artifacts

After decimating my model I end up with many long triangle faces all sharing a vertex:

[image]

When rendering, these regions show up with strange artifacts:

[image]

If I set shade flat for this model, the artifacts go away, but I would rather keep shade smooth on as overall it makes the model look better. Is there an easy fix for this? I am running a rendering pipeline on many models so a quick fix (or even a hack) without much computation required would be great.

Blender file showing the problem:

[image]

Comment: Have you activated the Auto Smooth option? If it still doesn't work please share your file

Comment: @moonboots Auto Smooth wasn't able to solve my problem without dropping the angle so low as to essentially turn off shade smooth for the whole model. I have updated the original question with a link to download the blend file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Auto Smooth* has not fixed your problem and working the topology would be a bit tedious, what you could do is give your object a *Weighted Normal* modifier, it will make Blender only try to smooth the small faces, not the big one, and your artefacts will disappear. Nota Bene: the *Weighted Normal* modifier needs the *Auto Smooth* to be activated.

[image]

A completely different solution would be to fake the 3 relief with a normal or height map.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to solve my problem perfectly. I can't fake the relief because these models are destined for 3D printing and casting so the geometry needs to really be there.

Comment: ok but changing the shading will only improve the rendering, 3D printing is another story...

Comment: The angles between the faces are tiny so they do not affect the casting at all, especially since everything is hand polished after casting.