# why are there weird shadows when shading smooth?

Tags: modeling, shadows

I'm trying to make a chopping board, and so far I've added a hole using a bool, and then added a bevel using a mod. However, when I try to shade it smooth, these unneeded shadows are formed. How do I fix it so that the shadow isnt cutting across a flat surface like it would a normal cutting board?

[image: shade flat] [image: shade smooth] [image: my topology]

Comment: Blender is trying to smooth between faces that are perpendicular and it gives this bad result, if the Auto Smooth option doesn't work, try the Weighted Normal modifier, see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258043/visual-artifacts-showing-up-on-decimated-model-set-to-shade-smooth/258055#258055

Comment: I'm either not doing it right, or its not working- Here is the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=0xEBqjvQ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/0xEBqjvQ/)

Comment: the *Weighted Normal* modifier needs the *Auto Smooth* to be activated

Comment: The top and bottom faces of your object are giant _N'Gon's_ (faces with more than 4 vertices). Blender's shading system is based on quads (which then get triangulated for shading purposes). The shading artifact you are seeing is the result of a failed triangulation. Re-topologize your mesh so that all faces are quads. Or for a "cheaper" solution, try selecting the top and bottom faces and insetting them slightly.